# how to fetch varchar date column with given date values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, mysqli

I have a table. In which, a column name is tb_date, which is varchar format. In that column dates are save, But in different-different format (Like: 01/07/201 OR 01-08-2018 or 2017/03/12 etc.). Now I want a search between given date. But it is not working. I tried it-

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from user_History") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
extract($row);
$time = strtotime( $tb_date );
$myDate = date( 'd/m/y', $time );

$result1=mysql_query("select * from user_History where '$myDate' BETWEEN '01/06/2018' AND '31/06/2018'") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    extract($row1);

    echo $tb_date;
    }                   
    }
```

But it is giving all records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are having the date values type as DATE in Mysql You should give it in the format of YYYY-MM-DD in the Sql statement.

Change

```
select * from user_History where '$myDate' BETWEEN '01/06/2018' AND '31/06/2018'
```

To

```
select * from user_History where `[DATE_COLUMN_NAME]` BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-31'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But error is giving Unknown column '1970197019701970-JanJan-ThuThu' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Edited the answer. Now look at the second statement. Replace the [DATE_COLUMN_NAME] with your field name which holds the date in the table.

Comment: Now it is continuous running past 2 mins.

Comment: how are you storing values in the field ? In other words, what is the data type for the field that holds your date values ?

Comment: datatype of tb_date column is varchar

Comment: Can you read the first statement of my answer ? and most of all you should never change the data types for date fields. You should always store dates in Date related data types.

Comment: Actually I developing only admin section with existing database in PHP. And data is coming from a APP and I can't change date format of table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174232/discussion-between-kishen-nagaraju-and-cloud-soft).

Comment: You'll never be able to search using the tb_date column, not only is it VARCHAR, a very bad idea, but from your question it doesn't even use a consistent date format. Basically that column is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this IF statement to convert this date formats, but it not the best idea. A better way is to normalize this field:

```
IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%Y/%m/%d'),
IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d/%m/%Y'),
IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d-%m-%Y') , 'ERROR'))) tb_date_new
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from user_History;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | tb_date    | some-field |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 01/07/2014 | Line 1     |
|  2 | 01-08-2018 | Line 2     |
|  3 | 2017/03/12 | Line 3     |
+----+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT u.*,
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%Y/%m/%d'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d/%m/%Y'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d-%m-%Y') , 'ERROR'))) tb_date_new
    -> FROM user_History u
    -> ;
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | tb_date    | some-field | tb_date_new |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 01/07/2014 | Line 1     | 2014-07-01  |
|  2 | 01-08-2018 | Line 2     | 2018-08-01  |
|  3 | 2017/03/12 | Line 3     | 2017-03-12  |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT u.*,
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%Y/%m/%d'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d/%m/%Y'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d-%m-%Y') , 'ERROR'))) tb_date_new
    -> FROM user_History u
    ->
    -> WHERE
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%Y/%m/%d'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d/%m/%Y'),
    -> IF( tb_date REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$', str_to_date(tb_date,'%d-%m-%Y') , 'ERROR')))
    -> BETWEEN str_to_date('01/06/2018','%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date('31/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y');
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | tb_date    | some-field | tb_date_new |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
|  2 | 01-08-2018 | Line 2     | 2018-08-01  |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```